# Why does Node.js's Mac Package ship with old version of npm? any issues?

Tags: node.js

I just installed the current version of node (3/14/16) 4.4.0 directly from Node.js via a Mac Package (the new suggested way, previously I installed via Homebrew).

I'm curious if anyone knows why the package ships with npm version 2.14.20, the book I'm going through suggests updating npm manually with the command

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

The version I see is now 3.8.1, that's quite a large difference hence my question, is it safe/smart to be this far ahead of what Node.js is officially putting out with their Mac package file?

**EDIT:**
It appears it's common for Node's recommended v4.x install to come with npm 2.x, the question that remains is, will there be any negative side effects of using the newest npm but an older version of node?

Comment: What is your current Node version?

Comment: 4.4.0 - original post edited

Comment: iirc, node 5.x comes with npm 3.x, and node 4.x comes with npm 2.x. note that node 4.4 is the LTS version and will remain supported (along with npm 2.x) for quite a while.

Comment: Interesting, I did notice when I went to Node.js/org the landing page suggests most users use 4.4.0 but does indeed say LTS (Long-Term Support) vs. the current stable release of 5.8.0

Comment: Aye, which is why I asked for your Node version. If you upgrade to stable, you should get NPM 3.x